# Django sort records by calculated field

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    score1 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    score2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    score3 = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

and I need to sort the records by the average score (i.e. `(score1 + score2 + score3)/3`) in descending order.

For the following list of `Person`s:

```
p1 = Person(score1=3, score2=4, score3=5) # avg = 4
p2 = Person(score1=3, score2=2, score3=1) # avg = 2
```

the result should be:

```
[<p2>, <p1>]
```

Comment: You can sort the fields manually after querying, or add a field to your model called `average` that you update on `def clean(self)`

Comment: it is very hard to understand what you want to do. can you try to better explain your problem?

Comment: i made some changes hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use F-expressions to annotate each row with the average score:

```
from django.db.models import F

ps_with_avg = Person.objects.annotate(
    avg=(F('score1')+F('score2')+F('score3'))/3
)
```

and then order them by the avg score like so:

```
ordered_ps = ps_with_avg.order_by('-avg')
```

Check the generated SQL to verify it does what you want:

```
print(ordered_ps.query)
```

Comment: That's a great improvement for me! Posted the same answer with you sir. Glad I could make it.

Comment: yeah this works great.thanks a lot.really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't I deserve an upvote :). At least to reach zero!

Comment: I did give an upvote, but mine won't be shown since my reputations is less than 15 :)

Comment: hello @Bahman Rouhani in the solution of hop he forgot to make the end result descending as you ask so you need to pus the - in the annotated field order_by(-avg) like this: ordered_ps = ps_with_avg.order_by('-avg')

Comment: @Reidel: weird… i was certain I put that there. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Bahman Rouhani: It was pleasure, I love Django and help people